# Function won't give revised results on changed parameter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that includes the following:

```
Public Function NumDisc() As Integer

NumDisc = DCount("*", "tblDisclosure", "Not IsNull(ReachedDBS) And ReachedDBS >" & MyDate)

End Function
```

‘MyDate’ is an unbound control. The form’s OnLoad event makes it twelve months ago (Date-365).

The intention is that on load a text box gives the number of applications sent to the DBS over the past twelve months.

On Loading the form the text box gives the correct number.

What I can’t do is get it to recalculate the number of applications from a different date. I have tried Refresh, Requery Repaint and the text box only ever shows the twelve month figure.

Comment: You've got a control, MyDate, and this initialises as required, and your function works. When you want to recalculate with a different date, what's happening? Is MyDate being edited? Whatever action requires the recalculation to occur must trigger some event (such as an _afterUpdate() event. I would suggest using this event, and forcing the NumDisc function to re-execute, by explicitly coding it: Numdisc().

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you assign a value to the Mydate control in the form_onload event. 
But its unclear :
When is the NumDisc function triggered ?
What type of control is Mydate ?

To achieve what you want,make Mydate another textbox if its not already a textbox.
Then add a call to NumDisc in the afterupdate event of Mydate textbox

From now, you should get results when you change the number in Mydate and press Enter

Comment: On Load the value of MyDate is today's date -365 (Date-365). It is a text box. NumDisc() is the Control source in a text box. If I 'Call NumDisc' in the afterupdate event of MyDate, nothing happens.

Comment: My apologies - I have just realised that after updating the date, the form starts 'calculating...' and never finishes aven if left a while. Perhaos connected to DLookup which I beleive can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Your title captures the problem: Your function has no parameters! You use the form value inside the function as if it were a parameter. It appears that you have a textbox that has its control source set to `=NumDisc()` . Since there are no parameters to that function, Access optimizes it; it figures that it can call it just once and it should give the same results every time. If you change the function definition to include a parameter:

```
Public Function NumDisc(vCompare As Variant) As Integer
    NumDisc = DCount("*", "tblDisclosure", "Not IsNull(ReachedDBS) And ReachedDBS > " & vCompare)
End Function
```

and change the control source to: `=NumDisc([Form].[MyDate])` then Access will know that the function needs to be called each time that [MyDate] changes.

Comment: Did exactly as you suggest (twice over) but nothing at all happened. I thought that MyDate was a parameter in NumDisc(), else why does it work OnLoad? Also can you explain vCompare?

Comment: Sorry - I now realise that if NumDisc() ignores MyDate in On Load, it will actually give correct data for the last twelve months as my data only goes back part of the last twelve months.

Comment: My apologies - I have just realised that after updating the date, the form starts 'calculating...' and never finishes aven if left a while. Perhaos connected to DLookup which I beleive can be slow.